# Jquery show server time

Tags: php, jquery

I have clock in my site showing server time (running)
sometimes it's stop working, And it's seems that he make the page run slower. There is better way to this it then this:

PHP:

```
 <?php print date("H:i", time()); ?>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function show_clock() {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/clock.php',
           timeout: 1000,
           success: function(data) {
              $("#servertime").html(data); 
              window.setTimeout(show_clock, 1000);
           },
          });
         }
         show_clock();
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: tired this code also, but seems not to be perfect too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>' //PHP method of getting server date

    var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

    function padlength(what){
        var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
        return output
    }

    function displaytime(){
        serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
        var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())
        document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML=timestring
    }

    setInterval("displaytime()", 1000)

</script>
```

Comment: every second is calling ajax because of getting server time? wow

Comment: Is this academic? I only ask because this is overkill for getting the time. You would be much better off working with the timezone and getting the offset when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

Why not get the server time when the page loads and then just increment it client side every second? Neither method is going to give an accurate version of what the server side time actually is though.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the above approach:

Overall, with the degree of accuracy you're showing to the user you could accomplish a clock in pure jQuery/JavaScript using the same time zone your server is located in (or seeding from an initial time set there). If you have multiple servers located geographically, then the above approach would still lead to non deterministic results and you may favor creating a JS clock based on UTC time.

As for the above jQuery:

This should be a GET instead of a POST request. The ajax call is also hitting your server every second for every user on your site, ouch.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I created a jQuery plugin that can take a server timestamp such as a PHP timestamp: https://github.com/JohnRDOrazio/jQuery-Clock-Plugin . An example:

```php
<?php
//Get a server side unix timestamp
$time = time();
?>
<input id="servertime" type="hidden" val="<?php echo $time; ?>" />
```

Then take that timestamp and feed it to the plugin when you initialize the clock:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
let servertime = parseInt( $("input#servertime").val() );
$("#clock").clock({"timestamp":servertime});
</script>
```

With this plugin you can format the date and the time any which way you want using PHP style format characters. See the github readme for more information.

I also [published the plugin to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-clock-plugin) for good measure.